# Why the mysql optimizer is not using the complete index?

Tags: mysql, explain, covering-index

I am trying to understand why MySQL is not using the complete index to answer the query. Let me explain.
I am using imdb database through MySQL version 5.1.73-1 (Debian). I created and index "itid_inf25_mid_ndx" on the table movie_info_idx with columns (info_type_id, info(25), movie_id). Columns info_type_id and movie_id are integer (NOT NULL) and info is TEXT type, so each index entry takes 4+27+4 = 35 bytes. The output for sentence:

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT movie_id
FROM movie_info_idx
WHERE info_type_id = 101
AND info > "9";
```

shows these values:

> select_type = SIMPLE; table = movie_info_idx; type=range;
>   possible_keys = itid_inf25_mid_ndx; key = itid_inf25_mid_ndx; key_len
>   = 31; ref = NULL; rows = 841; Extra = "Using where"

The key_len column and no "using index" in column extra are informing that just the columns (info_type_id,info(25)) which sum up 4+27 = 31 bytes are using from the index. I wonder why the optimizer is not using the column movie_id from the index in order to access the movie_id in the SELECT clause? It seems that the optimizer will access the base table movie_info_idx to take the movie_id value I want to list. Why?.

Thank you in advance for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

Once MySQL uses a query for a "range scan" (matching more than one value) it will generally no longer user the last column.

Reason for this is that multi-column indexes are a tree of trees.  In order to scan the index on the last column (movie_id) it has to search an index tree for every matching value of the range column (info).  This is generally inefficient and so MySQL won't do it.

To improve the situation, put the column expected to be the range scan last, so order it as (info_type_id, movie_id, info)

More info:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/multiple-column-indexes.html

Comment: Thank you Trent, but the query does not use the third column to filter rows. Mysql will use the index to retrieve entries with info_type_id = 101, this defines an index slice. Then the slice can be narrowed by taking entries with values having info > "9" and it can be done because info is the second column in the index (if you put info as the third column, mysql won't be able to use it in order to shorten the slice). After retrieving the final slice (101, > "9", *) all the necessary movie_id's are in these index slice, but the processor goes to the table in order to retrieve them Why?.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, however the answer is basically the same.  Once the range scan is done, MySQL generally won't use the next column in the index.  It may actually be just as efficient to do so (not actually sure) but MySQL just generally doesn't do it.

Comment: Ah ok, this is a convincing answer. Thank you for your interest.